# Unable to connect Autoware.auto and LGSVL with ROS2 native

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am trying to run LGSVL alongside autoware.auto but I am totally unable to make anything work. I am following thoses tutorials :

```
https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html
```

In the tutorial it is said to download the latest assets and setup the bridge as ROS2 native. But when starting the simulation with ROS2 native the simulator crashes with this error message in the command line : `Aborted (core dumped)`
And this error message in the web UI :

```
Invalid: type_support is null, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-dashing-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp-0.5.1/src/rmw_node.cpp:1311, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-dashing-rcl-0.7.9/src/rcl/publisher.c:171
```

Any idea ? Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363276/unable-to-connect-autoware.auto-and-lgsvl-with-ros2-native/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2020-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happens when you have not sourced the Autoware workspace first. Please make sure you run

```
ade$ source /opt/AutowareAuto/setup.bash
```

in a terminal before staring LGSVL *in the same terminal*.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2020-10-30**:
Thanks ! It works indeed !
What is the reason to use ROS2 Native instead of the classical ROS2 bridge ?

- Did you run into any difficulties with the ROS2 bridge ?
- No ROS2 bridge was available when you started ?

Thanks !

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-11-02**:
@Mackou The primary reason was that we were seeing very high CPU usage and dropped messages through the websockets-based bridge.